# Strange .htaccess on my host

Tags: css, wordpress, .htaccess

Today I entered my website and it's freak out. All css couldn't be loaded, all images too. I didn't update anything on my website for a few months. I investigated through the theme folder and found a **.htaccess** file in there (I used wordpress), and it' content.

Could any one can explain the meaning of this **.htaccess** file? I don't have any clue why this file appeared in my host.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterSanPOST Off
</IfModule>
#START #
Options +ExecCGI 
AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl pro
```

Comment: [`.htaccess`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess)

Comment: What is exact symptom of not loading images and css?.. Try to open one sample css directly, see what browser says (error message, HTTP response code). Debug HTTP response with firebug, if needed.

Comment: HTTP response code, it shows 404 error for css and images file

Comment: Look like something is trying to do something fishy. And your hoster does not allow that, hence the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess` is a hidden file, for it is started with a dot, that can use to configure the `RewriteEngine` of an Apache HTTP Server. `RewriteEngine` is use to rewrite or to redirect a URL into another URL, to URL rewriting *(or remapping)* or to URL redirecting. Just write `RewriteEngine off` in the `.htaccess` file if you want to turn the rewrite engine off.

Answer (score 0):

This .htaccess marks the directory as a CGI script directory, like cgi-bin, and says to try and run files with the listed extensions.  Trying to turn off mod_security most likely means that it was done without proper authority.  Have a look at the ownership of the .htaccess file, and the timestamps, and see if your own code made the change, or if it is possible that another user on the system made the change.